# How to change focus on Raspberry Pi camera?

Tags: camera

I'm having trouble getting the camera to loosen. I need to change the focus so I can attach an external wide angle lens to remove the blurriness. However, no amount of prodding seems to work. Has anyone done this and how did you do it?

Comment: It can be done. I heard of people remove it with a rubber erase (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=FPv1sMk_fv4&t=42). More info at http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/4279

Answer (score 3):

I had at it with a fine needle and lots of patience. You'll be able to remove the glue gradually.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this a few times. You want to hold the (square) camera base to stop it twisting off the PCB, I use needle nose pliers. Then you could use forceps or a cut up credit card spanner to turn the lens. I didn't have much luck scraping out the glue, but a gentle twist would crack it then they move easily.

I quick search found this: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1574661
if you have a 3d printer.

If you use forceps  have care not to scratch across the lens as they will probably slip before you break the glue. The credit card tool is described here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=145815&start=200

Mine is about 20mm across so I can refocus them when they are sat in an enclosure but something bigger will give you more leverage for the glue breaking.